# How to correctly include 3rd party AAR file in Ionic Cordova build

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, ionic4

I am working with Cordova 9.0.1 and ionic 5.4.14

I built a custom plugin using plugman and was able to successfully add it and call it from my ionic project with `ionic cordova run android`, verified by showing a toast which said "cheers!" (get it?)

So now I am working in Android Java by adding a 3rd party SDK for which I am trying to write a JavaScript bridge.

My project structure looks as follows:

```
MyProjectRoot
 -custom_plugins
   -MyCustomPlugin
     -src
       -android
         3rdPartySDK.aar
         mycustomplugin.gradle
         MyCustom.java
      -www
         MyCustom.js
       package.json
       plugin.xml
 -src
   USUAL-WEB-APP-STUFF-HERE
 ionic.config.json
 package.json
```

Remainder of project is not included for clarity, I believe these are the salient pieces.

The Cordova section of my package.json looks like:

```
"cordova": {
 "plugins": {
  "cordova-plugin-whitelist": {},
  "cordova-plugin-statusbar": {},
  "cordova-plugin-device": {},
  "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": {},
  "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": {
    "ANDROID_SUPPORT_ANNOTATIONS_VERSION": "27.+"
  },
  "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": {},
  "cordova-plugin-mycustomplugin": {}
},
"platforms": [
  "android"
]
}
```

I have added the mycustomplugin.gradle with the following:

```
 dependencies {
  compile(name:'3rdPartySDK', ext: 'aar') {
    transitive = true;
  }
 }
```

The android section of the plugin.xml looks like this:

```
 <platform name="android">
    <source-file src="src/android/MyCustom.java"
                 target-dir="src/cordova-plugin-mycustomplugin/MyCustomPlugin"/>
    <config-file parent="/*" target="res/xml/config.xml">
        <feature name="MyCustomPlugin">
            <param name="android-package" value="cordova.plugin.mycustomplugin.MyCustomPlugin"/>
        </feature>
    </config-file>
    <framework custom="true" src="src/android/mycustomplugin.gradle" type="gradleReference" />
    <lib-file src="src/android/3rdPartySDK.aar"/>
</platform>
```

My Java file looks something like this:

```
package cordova.plugin.mycustomplugin;

import com.3rd.party.sdk.MobileAPI;
import org.apache.cordova.CordovaPlugin;
import org.apache.cordova.CallbackContext;

public class MyCustom extends CordovaPlugin {

@Override
public boolean execute(String action, JSONArray args, CallbackContext callbackContext) throws JSONException {

 if (action.equals("initSDK")) {
        try {
            MobileAPI mobileAPI = MobileAPI.getInstance(cordova.getActivity().getApplicationContext());
            mobileAPI.destroy();
            mobileAPI.initSDK(2);
        }catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
         }
       }
 return false;
 }
```

Before trying to work with the 3rd party SDK, `ionic cordova run android` worked as expected.

Now, the `cordova.cmd build android` step fails with the message:

```
 Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.
 > Could not find :3rdPartySDK:.
 Required by:
 FAILED
  project :app
```

And I only got this far from a lot of Stack Overflow and search engine research.

What knowledge am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone else running across this here are the changes which fixed things for me:

1. create a lib directory in the custom_plugins/MyCustomPlugin/src/android directory
2. Move the aar file there
3. Add `compile(name:'3rdparty-sdk-4.1', ext: 'aar')` to the dependencies section of the build.gradle file
4. Add the following lines to android section of plugin.xml

   ```
    <source-file src="src/android/libs/3rdparty-sdk-4.1.aar" target-dir="libs"></source-file>
    <framework custom="true" src="src/android/build.gradle" type="gradleReference" />
   ```

Comment: Actually, it kind of half worked... it allowed my project to fully compile, but then, at runtime, none of the classes included on the external AAR were available.  What finally solved both problems was changing compile for implementation:

   dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.aar'], dir: 'libs')
   }

Answer (score 1):

What actually worked for me was, based on E. Manggini recomendation, replace `compile` with this form of `implementation`:

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.aar'], dir: 'libs')
}
```